# Is it possible to make a multiplayer game using hotspot with no 4G?

Tags: react-native

I wonder how I can create an app for my friends to play werewolf but with no Wi-fI just with a wireless hotspot that doesn't need 4G

Answer (score 0):

For a multiplayer game you need a network which the server needs a static ip address, so you can always use your access point to create a LAN, the hotspot on the phones would do the same, please be more specific if you need more help

Comment: I want to send and receive data using wireless hotspot (LAN) even without internet between more than 4 phones in the same time

Comment: Ofc it is possible, the more devices you wanna connect, the faster access point you need

Comment: Thanks but I want to know how